# How to send a post request with postman while also saving to a Mongo database?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, docker, flask, postman

I'm making a fictional character generator API. Runs fine when I send requests through Postman when run locally, but gives a 500 error and times out when run through docker. In the said flask API app:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
... 
class AddCharacter(Resource):
    def post(self):
...
        p.add_person()
        # saves the character to a mongodb
        p.save_person() #<-- causes a 500 error in postman when run through docker build and docker up
        retJson = {
            "Message": "Character has been created",
            "Status Code": 200
        }
        return jsonify(retJson)
```

How I connect to mongo:

```
db = MongoEngine()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'projectdb',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 27017


}

with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)
    try:
        db_client = db.connection['projectdb']
    except ConnectionFailure as e:
        sys.stderr.write("Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

the database manager:

```
class DatabaseManager():

    def save_user(self, first_name, last_name, openness, conscientiousness, extraversion,
                  agreeableness, emotional_stability, organization, anxiety,
                  knowledgeableness, sympathy, talkativeness, accommodation,
                  expressiveness, carefulness, depressiveness, gregariousness,
                  altruism, inquisitiveness):
        new_user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        new_user.save()
        new_personality = Personality(Openness=openness, Conscientiousness=conscientiousness, Extraversion=extraversion,
                                      Agreeableness=agreeableness, EmotionalStability=emotional_stability,
                                      Organization=organization, Anxiety=anxiety,
                                      Knowledgeableness=knowledgeableness, Sympathy=sympathy,
                                      Talkativeness=talkativeness, Accommodation=accommodation,
                                      Expressiveness=expressiveness, Carefulness=carefulness,
                                      Depressiveness=depressiveness, Gregariousness=gregariousness,
                                      Altruism=altruism, Inquisitiveness=inquisitiveness)
        new_profile = Profile(person=new_user, personality=new_personality)
        new_profile.save()
```

In the Person class:

```
def save_person(self):
    dm.save_user(first_name=self.first_name, last_name=self.last_name, openness=aff.Openness,
                 conscientiousness=aff.Conscientiousness, extraversion=aff.Extraversion,
                 agreeableness=aff.Agreeableness, emotional_stability=aff.EmotionalStability,
                 organization=aff.Organization, anxiety=aff.Anxiety,
                 knowledgeableness=aff.Knowledgeableness, sympathy=aff.Sympathy, talkativeness=aff.Talkativeness,
                 accommodation=aff.Accommodation,
                 expressiveness=aff.Expressiveness, carefulness=aff.Carefulness, depressiveness=aff.Depressiveness,
                 gregariousness=aff.Gregariousness,
                 altruism=aff.Altruism, inquisitiveness=aff.Inquisitiveness)
```

[image: file structure]
[image: Dockerfile]
[image: requirements.txt]
[image: .yml file]

file structure,
Dockerfile,
requirements.txt,
.yml file images. 
I run docker with `sudo docker-compose build` and then `sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: If your code works just fine on local and not on docker, it's probably an issue with how you run your docker container. Please add how you build your image and how you run it.

Comment: Added additional image building files. I want to add the clarification that AddCharacter runs fine on docker when it is not attempting to save to mongo. Something makes postman time out when writing to the mongo db through docker.

Comment: How do you connect your flask app to mongo? What hostname do you use?

Comment: Added how I connect the flask app.py to mongo. I use 'localhost' and port: 27017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found adding networks to the docker-compose.yml fixed the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your setup that the host machine is running the database server, which you are unable to reach from your container's virtual network, what you need to do here is interface the host network and ports with container's virtual network so that your application is able to reach the database as it is able to when running on the same host according to your application config.

By default, a docker container starts in bridge mode nothing is explicitly specified about network modes when starting up the container, so either you can bind database server with the bridge IP or you can specify the network mode to host for your container.

Comment: Thanks! How and where do I interface the host network and ports with the container's virtual network?

Comment: to get the bridge IP you could run the `route` command from the inside of a container to have a look at the routing table and bind the db server with that IP or if you just want to test using this machine only you could specify `--network="host"` flag when starting up the docker container. Source: [for more info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you connect to MongoDB from the backend.

Keep in mind that `localhost` for a docker container is different than the running host, and points to the container itself (unless you run containers in host network). So almost 99% of times you don't want to connect to `localhost` in a dockerized environment.

By default, docker-compose creates an internal network between running containers, such that you can resolve a container's ip by its service name. That is, if you replace `localhost` with `db` (your database service name), you can connect to your database.